# Validation on Redirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

validation.java

```
     try
    {
        conn = dsEvent.getConnection();
        String userCheck = "select * from customer";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(userCheck);
        while(rs.next()){
           if((email.equals(rs.getString("email")))&&(password.equals(rs.getString("password"))))
           {
               RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
               rd.forward(req,res);
           }
           else
           {
              req.getSession().setAttribute("error", "The email or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again");
            res.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/index.jsp");
           }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
  <body>
    <h2>System</h2>
    <p style ="color:red"><%=session.getAttribute("error")!=null ? "":session.getAttribute("error") %></p>
    <form method ="post" action="validation">
        Please Login: <br/>
        Email: <input type="email" name="email" required/><br/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password" required/><br/>
        <input type ="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm doing a validation for email and password. So when user input correct email and password it will forward to success.jsp. And if the user input wrong details, it will redirect the page to index.jsp together with the error.

But I can't seem to get it work on the wrong detail parts.It gave me

> WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[com.events.ValidationServlet]: PWC1406:
>   Servlet.service() for servlet com.events.ValidationServlet threw
>   exception

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `ResultSet` contains at least two rows, so the server is executing the forward and/or the redirect or a combination of both at least two times, which is not allowed since you're trying to write the response when it's already closed.

**Solution:** Move the validation code outside any loop. Make sure the call to `RequestDispatcher#forward` or `HttpServletResponse#redirect` occurs **once** only in your method in servlet.

Also, I don't recommend using redirect in this case, because it generates a new request/response cycle so all the attributes stored in the request won't pass to this new request/response.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to Java so it will be good if you could simplify it. And sorry again about the part that I think you might misunderstand it, what went wrong is I couldn't went back to jsp after the the wrong detail input, and if they were to go back, it would prompt me the message that said " the email and password .......".

Answer (score 0):

Why are you iterating through whole `resultset` and validating if user is present or not instead try changing your `select` query to check if particular user is present in your database or not.

To do that try below code

```
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
String userCheck = "select * from tableName where username = ? AND password = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(userCheck);
ps.setString(1, email);
ps.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

And than just check whether `resultset` is empty or not.

To check resultset is empty or not put below code:

```
if(rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("email",email);
    response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
} else {
    request.setAttribute("error", "Invalid Username & Password");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

For `isBeforeFirst()` method look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

Also change `index.jsp` to show error message

```
<p style ="color:red"><%=request.getAttribute("error")!=null ? request.getAttribute("error"): "" %></p>
```

Comment: Please do not teach to build requests by concatenating input strings : this construct is at the base of SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly an addition to Luiggi Mendoza's answer. **You cannot have `forward` or `sendRedirect` inside a loop** except if you pass only once in the loop. As you have, the servlet throws an exception what is causing your error.

You could move those codes outside the loop :

```
    boolean found = false;
    while( (! found) && rs.next()){
       if((email.equals(rs.getString("email")))&&(password.equals(rs.getString("password"))))
       {
           found = true;
       }
    }
    if (found) {
       RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
       rd.forward(req,res);
    }
    else
    {
       req.getSession().setAttribute("error", "The email or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again");
       res.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/index.jsp");
    }
```

But here you are looping *by hand* on a resultset, when you could let the database find if there is a match :

```
    conn = dsEvent.getConnection();
    String userCheck = "select count(*) from customer where email = ? and password = ?";
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement();
    stmt.setString(1, email);
    stmt.setString(2, password);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(userCheck);
    if (rs.next().getInt(1) > 0) 
       RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
       rd.forward(req,res);
    }
    else
    {
       req.getSession().setAttribute("error", "The email or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again");
       res.sendRedirect(this.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/index.jsp");
    }
```

Comment: I tried your first method, it worked! =). But when i reopen my application, the error message remain still when I didn't enter any detail yet.

Comment: It seem that something is incorrect on this sentence when showing error message.<p style ="color:red"><%=session.getAttribute("error") != null ? session.getAttribute("error"):""%></p>